# Do all I-type instructions take the same number of cycles on a multi-cycle MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture

Do all I-type MIPS instructions take the same number of cycles in a multi-cycle datapath? I know R-type have the same number of cycles.

Comment: I'd guess that most designs would take the same number of cycles as for R-type instructions, since MIPS is designed to be pipelined at 1/clock.  For any particular multi-cycle datapath, though, you'd have to check.  Someone could certainly choose to take an extra cycle, or maybe take one less cycle if they normally take 2 cycles to read register operands from a single-ported register file.  Of course, I-type instructions include relative branches, and they may be special.  (But R-type includes jump-to-register.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do all I-type MIPS instructions take the same number of cycles in a multi-cycle datapath?

No.

First, let's look at some of the instructions are included in the MIPS I-Type category: `addi` and `lw`.  These are both I-Type instructions — with the identical 16-bit immediate and rs and rt fields.  They are decoded using the same fields, which is why they are both considered I-Type instructions.

Ok, next, let's look at the multicycle processor.  This is not a pipelined processor, though, generally speaking, it will have a cycle for each stage in an equivalent pipelined version.

While we would generally find a pipelined processor's performance superior at the same megahertz, one advantage of a multicycle processor implementation over a pipelined processor implementation is that "stages" that are not needed can be skipped (skipping a cycle is not viable in a pipelined processor because of the instruction execution overlap; whereas the multicycle processor does not overlap execution of instructions).

So, among IF, ID, EX, MEM, WB stages, `addi` does not require or make use of the MEM stage, and thus it would be silly not to skip that cycle, making `addi` a 4 cycle instruction.

However, `lw`, does require the MEM stage (so all the stages) hence it will be 1 cycle longer than `addi`.

Comment: Can we say the same about R-Type? for example add and slt,  I know that add is a 4 cycle instruction.

Comment: There are no equivalents to `lw`/`sw` (i.e. requiring MEM stage) in R-Type. To be clear, there could have been -- but such were never defined. For example, a hypothetical instruction: `lw rt, (rs, rd)` would have been an R-Type that sources 2 registers, as another addressing mode, the addition result (rs+rd) being the address for memory, and then rt the target -- very much like lw rt, d(rs), but 2 registers instead of reg & imm.  These would have taken valuable opcode space (in the limited R-Type func field), since byte, half, signed & unsigned, word & stores as well would have been expected.